# Prove $h(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx$ is continuous if $f(x,y)$ is continuous for every fixed $x$ and $f(x,y)$ is integrable for every fixed $y$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Define a function $f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for every fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)$ is continuous. And suppose that for every fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x,y)$ is integrable. Suppose also that there exists an integrable function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x,y)| \le g(x)$ for all $x,y$. Show that the function $h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx$ is continuous.

So far, all I have really gotten is that, since $f(x,y)$ is continuous for every fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta_x > 0 $ such that $| f(x,y) - f(x,z) | < \epsilon$, $\forall y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ with $| y - z | < \delta_x$. So then we have
$$
| h(y) - h(z)| = \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} (f(x,y) - f(x,z)) dx \right|
$$
 and we can then say something about $f(x,y)$ being continuous for every fixed $x$.

From here I am stuck; the tightest bound I've been getting is an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ of a constant.

Any hints are appreciated!!

Comment: The statement in the title is false.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Title is incomplete.  The body of the question includes the hypothesis that $|f(x,y)| \leqslant g(x)$ for all $x,y$ where $g$ is integrable. Of course, without this we can find counterexamples where $\lim_{y \to y_0} h(y) \neq h(y_0)$.

Comment: @RRL Thanks. I am aware of that and I have given an upvote for your answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint -- assuming as stated in the body of the question that $|f(x,y)| \leqslant g(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$ where $g$ is integrable:

Given a fixed $y_0$ and a sequence $y_n \to y_0$, we have by continuity $f(x,y_n) \to f(x,y_0)$. Now apply the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to

$$h(y_n) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y_n) \, dx$$